# Azure K8S Calico network policy is recommended for dev/test configuration. Not suitable for Production?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, calico, cni

I am trying to create an Azure Kubernetes - AKS for production workload.

May be I am misinterpreting the term 'Calico network policy is recommended for dev/test configuration.' is it mean i should NOT use Calico for Production workload AKS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calico network policy is suitable for production workloads on AKS. Calico provides a richer feature set, including support for Windows nodes and supports Azure CNI as well as Kubenet.

[image]

Calico is widely used in production environments. The note in the Azure interface suggesting that Calico is recommended for dev/test configurations could be based on its ease of setup and management.
[image]

If you are planning to go ahead with Calico for your production setup, you can go ahead without any hesitation.

[image]

Azure suggests Azure CNI as a default option for production Kubernetes clusters due to its seamless integration with Azure's native virtual networking environment. Obviously because it's from azure. It's just that if you use [Azure Container Networking Interface (CNI)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-container-networking/blob/master/docs/cni.md), with Azure option, every pod gets an IP address from the subnet and can be accessed directly.

Check out these documents for better clarity on [Calico](https://www.suse.com/c/rancher_blog/comparing-kubernetes-cni-providers-flannel-calico-canal-and-weave/) and [Azure CNI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/hybrid/concepts-container-networking#kubernetes-networks) and decide which suits your need based on your current environment.

References:

- [Container networking concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/hybrid/concepts-container-networking#kubernetes-networks)
- [Best practices for containers on AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-best-practices#networking)
- [Networking policy between Calico and Azure CNI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/aks/service-fabric-azure-kubernetes-service#networking)
- [Best practices for network connectivity and security in AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-network#choose-the-appropriate-network-model)